# Scalatra - change port for standalone server

Tags: sbt, scalatra

I am developing a Scalatra application and require the port to be different than the default port 8080. I added the following to the end of my build.sbt:

```
containerPort in Jetty := 8089
```

This works great when I am starting the Jetty server within the sbt console (i.e. using `jetty:start`) but it doesn't work when I create a standalone .jar file using `sbt-assembly`. When I run the .jar, it still starts the server on port 8080.

Is there something additionally that I need to add to my build.sbt or elsewhere to ensure that `sbt-assembly` will properly recognize my desired port number?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Scalatra doesn't support creating a standalone jar natively. How do you create the standalone jar?

Comment: I used sbt assembly. I should probably add an answer to this and close the question...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by editing the default port in the Bootstrap file. Wasn't able to find a way to do it with changes in the build.sbt file.